# Redshift PG_TABLE_DEF table listing unknown tables

Tags: redshift, data-dictionary

When I count number of tables in my schema manually, it is 220.

When I count number of views in my schema manually, it is 23.

220 + 23 = **243**

However, this query:

```
select count(distinct tablename) from PG_TABLE_DEF where schemaname='myschema'
```

returns **305**.

Why is there a mismatch?

Comment: Found answer. In PG_TABLE_DEF some rows are created with tablename column ="<table_name>_pkey", when that table has primary key column. So PG_TABLE_DEF contains tables, views and indexes also.

Comment: You should post this comment as a self-answer so that other can benefit from it; comments often disappear.